# How to set up prettier on vscode for css modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

Prettier is formatting my `module.css` files strangely.

Expected:

```
.foo {
  @apply 
  border-2
  rounded
}
```

Actual (the first style is moved next to apply and a ; is added to the end

```
.foo {
  @apply border-2
  rounded;
}
```

All other files are formatted correctly.

It is detecting that the file is CSS.

Here is the vscode output after saving a module.css file

```
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] Formatting file:///src/components/Card/Card.module.css
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] Using config file at '/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] Using ignore file (if present) at /.prettierignore
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "css"
}
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/src/components/Card/Card.module.css",
  "parser": "css",
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "printWidth": 120
}
["INFO" - 4:12:25 PM] Formatting completed in 0.01ms.
```

Answer (score 3):

You should separate class names in `@apply` with spaces instead of new lines as it is probably struggling to handle your invalid vanilla CSS (`@apply` is an extension upon the language):

```css
.foo {
  @apply border-2 rounded;
}
```

[Prettier Playground Link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEA6AhgZwCYDMAEwAOlPvgALoAOVANgJ74zoCWtA7i1NvmJpvgAWMALa0A3CQC+IADQgIVGC2iZkodACdNEdgAUtCNSnQd09NfIBGm9GADWcGAGUqdrgHNkMTQFc48nAiVnDY2KEAMuhQHr7oHnAAYhCaIugwyjHIIOi+MBByIMJiAOqCLPCYbmBwzkYVLABuFfTZfJYgXJhwmjB6th5pyLim3fIAVpgAHgBCtg5OzugicBFccMOjASCTU86etHAAir4Q8Ju0YyBumt2abfyFVJpcMCUs2DCCyAAcAAzyZ4QbolWxUbLPOB3RobeQAR1O8H6imMOUwAFooHBQqFCpo4AiWPj+vEhkgRpdtt0RCxvH4qQdjoiNuStvJmFZ3p9vkgAEzs2xsTwAYQgIjJIChAFZCr5ugAVdBWYwUq6NfwASW4CBcYBeSgAgtxnDB6IcLt0pFIgA)

Answer (score 0):

you don`t have to use new lines in @apply you can use space like that:

```css
.foo {
      @apply border-2 rounded; // don`t use new line
}
```